# Encoding UTF8 return nil Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, encoding, utf-8

I’m trying to download a csv file with characters like « àéèäâ », using Firebase.
As you can see, i’m using Swift3 encoding function:

String(bytes: data!, encoding: .utf8)

**In my code:**

```
func downloadMyCSVWithDLURL(csvName: String, modeType: Bool, modeSync: Bool){
        let realm = try! Realm()

        //Firebase Storage Reference
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

        //Firebase Path to my csv file
        if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid) != nil {
            let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
            let downloadRef = storage.reference(forURL:  "\(REF_USERS_CSV_FOLDER)").child("USERS_BDD_CSV/\(userID!)/\(csvName).csv")

            //Download csv file in "data" as NSData
            downloadRef.data(withMaxSize: 1000000, completion: { (data, err) in

                //Encoding
                let rawString = String(bytes: data!, encoding: .utf8)

                let rawLines = rawString?.components(separatedBy: ["\n"])
                let count = rawLines?.count
                var tableParticipant = [Participant]()

                for i in 1...count! {
                        let datas = rawLines![i].components(separatedBy: ";")
[...]
}
```

- data and data! = 1586ko bytes, the right size of my csv.

**An example of my CSV:**

```
id;lastname;firstname;phoneNBR;mail;qrCode;address;cp;city;company;plusOne;entryType;eventName;isCheck;liveInscr;dateInscr;dateCheck
424ad79a;DOE;Johnàéèäâ;22222222222;doe@john.com;QRcode;14 George Street;2000;Sydney;COMPANY;;VIP;XXX;false;false;null;null
```

**Error:**

[image: My error]
*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)*

- Let rawString = nil
- Let rawLines = nil
- Let count = nil

If my variables are nil, it's because of the "àéèäâ" in my csv, the encoding fail and return nil, I guess.

By the way, without this special character, the encoding don't return nil and my app works pretty well.

Why does the utf8 encoding fail?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your CSV is not UTF8 encoded

Comment: Thank you, you’r right, after rencoding my csv file to utf8, the app doesn’t crash anymore. But special character appears instead of the right one.

Comment: SO just use the original encoding method when reading it `String(bytes: data, encoding: .whatever)`